# Emacs: can I limit a number of lines in a buffer

Tags: debugging, emacs, lisp, elisp

For debugging an application via Emacs and gdb, the number of lines of a debug output sometimes may quickly overcome 9xxxx. Is there a way to force Emacs into removing old lines after the number exceed e.g. 1000?

Comment: Do you have a variable such as `gdb-debug-log-max`?  Or perhaps the equivalent for a `*Messages*` buffer, such as `message-log-max`?

Comment: @lawlist yes, the first one set to 128, the second to 1000. Though I am use the `shell` mode because both the `gud-gdb` and `gdb` has a problems. Anyway, I am just tested: even in `gdb` mode the lines doesn't get removed after the number bypasses either 128 either 1000.

Comment: How about something like the variable `comint-buffer-maximum-size` and the function `comint-truncate-buffer`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell-Mode.html  I'm just guessing, but that's the general idea.  There are other shell mode type major modes and the variable may be different depending on which mode -- e.g., ansi-term may use something like `term-buffer-maximum-size`.

Comment: @lawlist aha! You may post an answer: setting the hook `(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
                    'comint-truncate-buffer)` do the job. The number of lines managed by the `comint-buffer-maximum-size` variable, it is would be the number you're set plus 1 *(I suppose that ⁺¹ due to a bug)*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
M-x comint-truncate-buffer
```

This command truncates the shell buffer to a certain maximum number of lines, specified by the variable `comint-buffer-maximum-size`. Here's how to do this automatically each time you get output from the subshell:

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions 'comint-truncate-buffer)
```

---

As to the variable `comint-buffer-maximum-size`, the print-out from `describe-variable` is as follows:

`comint-buffer-maximum-size` is a variable defined in `comint.el`.  Its value is 1024

Documentation:

The maximum size in lines for Comint buffers.  Comint buffers are truncated from the top to be no greater than this number, if the function `comint-truncate-buffer' is on`comint-output-filter-functions'.

You can customize this variable.